# Refresh TableView after Thread executions

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2

In my application, I load a table with data.
In this tab, one column come from a webservice which can make some times to answer.
So I treat this one in pool thread to avoid to block the screen like this:

```
    final ObservableList<StockListBean> list = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList();
    list.addAll(stocksListMService.getStocksListRunning());
    stocksList.setItems(list);

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (final StockListBean stockListBean : list) {
        executor.execute(new Task<Float>() {
        @Override
        protected Float call() throws Exception {
            logger.debug("In jfx task for {}", stockListBean.getCode());
((StockListRunningBean)stockListBean).setActualPrice(stocksListMService.getActualPrice(stockListBean.getCode()));
              columnActualPrice.setVisible(false);
              columnActualPrice.setVisible(true);
              return 0f;
             }
          });
    }
```

Threads are well execute and data are well set in beans but I don't reach to refresh the tableView.
I try code in the snapshot. I try many other ways found on the web but nothing to do, the column is desperately empty.

If I keep the thread loop but without execute the service and set a default value, the column is not empty.

It's such a real problem with screen refresh.

How can I refresh this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `StockListRunningBean` uses JavaFX observable properties, so that the TableView sees the changes, you shouldn't need to do anything additional to update the table. One problem with your code is that you're making changes to the UI (via changes to the StockListRunningBean price property) from a thread that's not the FX Application Thread.

Try this refactoring:

```
for (final StockListBean stockListBean : list) {
    final int code = stockListBean.getCode(); // assuming int, change as required
    final Task<Float> task = new Task<Float>() {
        @Override
        protected Float call() throws Exception {
            logger.debug("In jfx task for {}", code);
            return stocksListMService.getActualPrice(code);
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            ((StockListRunningBean)stockListBean).setActualPrice(task.getValue());
        }
    });
    executor.execute(task);
}
```

Again, this assumes that your StockListRunnerBean has a 
`public FloatProperty actualPriceProperty() {...}`
method and that the table column is properly bound to it.

Comment: I've found that executors don't throw exceptions, just shut down.  If you wrap the method that is calling the UI thread in a try block you might see the error.  A real pain for debugging and finding errors in threads.

Comment: If exceptions are occurring, the way to handle them is to register a `setOnFailed` handler with the task: `task.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {...});`

Comment: No exception throw by the service. My stockListBean is not JFX observable because it is use by several applications. I need simple variable type. The task allow to get the thread in FX Application thread.

Comment: @James_D That works for letting you know an error occurred, which is usually already obvious.  It doesn't tell you what the error is, I need a stack trace.  It's a bit deceptive since task.call() says throws exception, but if I wrap the start() method in a try catch it doesn't get the exception.

Comment: A note, I'll try with a FXObservable bean and I get the same problem.

Comment: @Kiva Yes, I was going to recommend that. I think that's the problem. Without the observable properties you may have to do something ugly, like remove the element from the list and add it back.

Comment: @brian In the setOnFailed handler you can call `task.getException()` to get a reference to the exception, and `task.getException().printStackTrace(...)`. There's no way that wrapping `start()` in a `try{...} catch(...){...}` could be made to work. Since the exception's thrown asynchronously, when would you expect the `catch` block to be executed?

Comment: @James_D, I tried with FXObservable bean but I get the same problem. I tried to clean the item list and refill it but same problem.

Comment: @James_D, thanks.  It works perfectly.  Now I can find out when an executor goes bad.  I would suggest adding that to Kiva's example and maybe he can find where the error is.

Comment: @brian, my service works well, it's not the problem.

Comment: @Kiva Compare to [this mock example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/9763272). See if that helps.

Comment: Ok my apologize to James_D, I add a setOnFailed method and I get this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8 (dammit). If I do "task.run()" I block my screen and I don't want it, how can I fix it ?

Comment: Move the code that updates the UI from your thread to the onSucceeded(...) handler, as in my answer above.

Comment: "my service works well, it's not the problem"  I realize that and I see you've figured it out as well.  When using an executor the errors inside the task don't show up without that extra code from James_D.

Comment: Kiva, I use Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
               Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
                    , (Runnable r) -> {
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                     t.setDaemon(true);
                    return t;
                });  To get my executor.  It will use all the cores on any machine and the threads are daemon so they don't keep the VM running.  Check your task list and see if you still have the threads after stopping the program.  Alternatively, I think you can call executor.shutdown.

Comment: Ok James_D, this work well when I move the code on setOnSucceeded method. Thanks you very much.